# Not able to listen for updates for BP, Temperature & Blood glucose In HistoryClient using listener in Android

Tags: android, google-fit

I m working on a fitness tracking app. I would like to listen for "BP,temperature,& body weight" parameters. 
My app needs to get a callback when these type of data get inserted into google fit repository.
How do I listen for such update?

Currently the HistoryClient, as mentioned in [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient) , will do this job but it doesn't support for "BP, and Temperature"

My requirement is : When temperature,body weight,blood pressure reading is inserted into google fit repository, My app needs to get a callback,fetch the data and sync it to server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this for BP/Temperature but can do this for [weight](http://%20https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient.html#registerDataUpdateListener(com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataUpdateListenerRegistrationRequest))

Comment: I know that i am looking to get callback when there is update in BP and Temperature :)

Answer (score 0):

Can not comment as of yet.

I am experiencing a similar issue for regitsering a DataUpdateListener  for HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE.
It simply returns [error code 5008](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessStatusCodes) in the failure handler every time.

Our application is in Internal Testing and has all the proper permissions granted by user (me) when testing.

Even when retrying to register for Blood Pressure, as error code says you should, it still returns 5008 as the error in failure handler.

It has worked so far for Weight and Body Fat.

[Sessions](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions) should not apply as a way to listen a Data Type like Blood pressure, neither should it be from a [subscription](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record).
It could be done through the use of the sensor API, but its not really appropriate for your situation (and mine)

It should be done through the [Data Updates](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#register-for-updates) method on historical data. As of writing, the [list of supported Data Types](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient#public-taskvoid-registerdataupdatelistener-dataupdatelistenerregistrationrequest-request) for this method does not include Blood Pressure